# UIView gradient color not rendered properly in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a custom `UICollectionViewCell` and the problem that I'm facing is rendering the UI right after the cell is being loaded. You can see from the screenshot below, the first cell loads the `dimView` properly (it has a gradient background color) but any other cell does not.

[image]

Worth mentioning is that this view is visible once the user swipe the cell left or right (it creates a flip illusion where it hides an image and shows this view).

If the cell is reused, it's rendered properly, but not when it's initially loaded. Is there another method where I should call this function `showDimViewAndCheckmark()`??

```
@IBOutlet weak var backView: UIView!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    setUI()
}

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    setUI()
}

override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()
    setUI()
}

 func setUI() {
    coverImageView.clipsToBounds = true
    backView.setGradientBackground(colorOne: Colors.purpleDarker, colorTwo: Colors.purpleLight)
    backView.layer.maskedCorners =  [.layerMaxXMinYCorner, .layerMaxXMaxYCorner]

    layer.shadowColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
    layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width:1, height: 1)
    layer.shadowRadius = 2.0
    layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
    layer.masksToBounds = false

    contentView.clipsToBounds = true
    contentView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    contentView.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMaxXMinYCorner, .layerMaxXMaxYCorner]
}
```

Comment: Call your function in layoutSubviews()

Comment: I tried, no effect really

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
draw(_ rect: CGRect)
```

Try this method.